# Call an ORACLE Stored Procedure from Excel VBA, including string and number parameters

Tags: oracle, vba, excel, stored-procedures

Hi StackOverflow friends,

I would like to ask you how to **call an ORACLE Stored Procedure from Excel VBA, including two different parameters kind (string and number)**. I have been looking for in StackOverflow and Google how to do it, but I never find a good answer. So, I have decided to ask here for this specific matter.

I have this **ORACLE Stored Procedure**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE InsertDayTable (
    PNTable    in VARCHAR2,
    PMonth     in VARCHAR2,
    PDay       in VARCHAR2,
    PProvince  in VARCHAR2,
    PBusiness  in VARCHAR2,
    PCode      in NUMBER,
    PValue     in NUMBER,
    PAccum     in NUMBER
) AS
    v_sql         VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
    /*
     *  Development of the procedure...
     */
END;
```

I have an **Excel file** used like a program, where I calculate the data to insert in ORACLE. After calculate this data, I send it to an Excel procedure. This **Excel procedure is responsible for call the ORACLE Stored Procedure**. However, I don't know how to call using VARCHAR2 and NUMBER parameters.

For VARCHAR2 parameters, I am using:

```
Set oParam1 = oCmd.CreateParameter("PNTable", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, "MyTable")
oCmd.Parameters.Append oParam1
```

For NUMBER parameters, I am using:

```
Set oParam7 = oCmd.CreateParameter("PValue", adNumeric, adParamInput, 5, iValue)
```

However, I always have errors (**Error '-2147217887 (80040e21)'**), don't matter the changes that I make. Could you help me with some tips or an example? Thank you very much.

Comment: I found out the solution.

Comment: I found out the solution. I tried to post it, but I have not permission to share it. I wanted to share a wide answer. However: For VARCHAR2: `Set oParam1 = oCmd.CreateParameter("PNTable", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, "MyTable")` For NUMBER: `Set oParam7 = oCmd.CreateParameter("PValue", adNumeric, adParamInput, , iValue)` `oParam7.Precision = 38`.

Comment: If you need more information, please tell me.